# use binds in viewmodels

Tags: c#, xaml

I am doing a project and in one xaml page I have some `Textblock` with bind like this

```
<PivotItem Header="Lista">
   <ListView x:Name="List1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProdutoViewModel.Produtos}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="list:Produto">`
                ...
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="nome" Text="{x:Bind Nome, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Preco, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Disponivel, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Fornecedor, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Categoria, Mode=OneWay}" />
            <Image Source="Assets/mouse.png" />
            <Image Source="Assets/teclado.png"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
</PivotItem>
```

And then I have another `pivot` like this

```
<PivotItem>
 <PivotItem Header="Carrinho">
   <ListView x:Name="Cart" ItemsSource="{x:Bind EncomendaProdutoViewModel.EncomendaProdutos}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:DataType="list:EncomendaProduto">
        <StackPanel>
         <Button x:Name="pay" Content="Pagar" Click="Payment_click"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Quantidade, Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Preco, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </PivotItem>
```

How can I show the data from the first `pivot` into the second? I have a button on the first `pivotitem` for each product and when I press it, I want to add the data of that product to the second `pivotitem`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an outer view-model, like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MasterViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

class MasterViewModel 
{
    public ProdutoViewModel ProdutoViewModel { get; set; }
    public EncomendaProdutoViewModel EncomendaProdutoViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Then bind to the Pivot like this:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ProdutoViewModel.Produtos}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.EncomendaProdutoViewModel.EncomendaProdutos}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.EncomendaProdutoViewModelSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Then, handle the selection in code-behind:

```
class MasterViewModel 
{
    public ProdutoViewModel ProdutoViewModel { get; set; }
    public EncomendaProdutoViewModel EncomendaProdutoViewModel { get; set; }

    Producto _ProdutoViewModel;
    public Producto ProdutoViewModel 
    { 
        get { return _ProdutoViewModel; } 
        set { 
                _ProdutoViewModel = value;
                EncomendaProdutoViewModel.EncomendaProdutos.Add(value); 
            } 
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Best of luck!

Comment: I think i did like you said, created a new viewmodel but i don't know where the page.datacontext go.
But i add that to my pivotitems and i put the code on that code-behind but i think i still have and error of conversion because because this 2 viewmodel are different.